# How do I populate a list of email groups from active directory into an array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript, active-directory

I have been tasked with creating a web form doing employee change requests and want to do 2 list boxes to in which to add/remove email group access and wanted to get the list of email groups from our active directory.  I was curious how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Download and have a go with the ADSI scriptomatic:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939958

It's really very good.